# How to install a newer version of libav than what is in the repos

Tags: apt, package-management, ffmpeg, debian, libav

I'm currently running debian 7 wheezy, but the package management system is the same as ubuntu so I thought I'd ask here.  I'm trying to install at least version 9.x of libav.  The current version in the repos is 0.8.x.  I added the debian wheezy backports repo to my sources.list but it doesn't have any newer versions of libav.  How can I install a newer version?

Comment: What, exactly, does this have to do with ffmpeg? The ffmpeg tag shouldn't be mixed with the libav tag unless you're using both.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I'm sure you are aware that libav is a fork of ffmpeg.  The earlier releases of libav (including the one referenced here) still export the ffmpeg command.  I'm sure there are many users, myself included, who were using "ffmpeg" not realizing it was actually libav, which created a bit of extra confusion when trying to upgrade "ffmpeg".  If the tag helps others trying to upgrade "ffmpeg" realize they really need to upgrade libav, then I think the tag makes sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wasn't running the backports install correctly.  The `-t wheezy-backports` is necessary.

It installs version 6.x, but it has the options I need.

http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

```
apt-get -t wheezy-backports install "libav-tools"
```